# Can Perl or VB script access an email folder in outlook, find and open a hyperlink (in IE) in each email and save the linked document to a folder?

Tags: vb.net, perl, outlook

I'm not proficient at developing/using scripts and wanted to know if something already exists that I could plug in to a rule using MS Outlook.  I have all emails with a particular topic being saved to an Outlook folder and there is an option (in the advanced rule settings) to run a script on the email when it arrives? Can Perl, VB or similar program scan the content of the email to the hyperlink(s), open up the link in IE and save the document (pdf) to a folder on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple answer, then the answer would be "yes".

Using Perl, you can use modules such as [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm), and [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm). How? You would use `Win32::OLE` to scan through a specific Outlook folder for emails, read its contents and save it as text files, you can then read the text file and get the `PDF` url from it and use `LWP::UserAgent` to fetch and download the `PDF` document and once you are done delete the text file.

You can install these modules using `cpan` prompt (using Windows command prompt if you have perl installed) or you can use `PPM` (Perl Package Manager) to install these modules as well.

I also think that it could be easily achieved by a `VBScript` and would make more sense since its a Microsoft product and it might not require you to install any third party libraries as well, but I am no `VBScript` expert and can't help you much in that regard.